# Client-side JavaScript Facebook OAuth2 implementation?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, client-side, facebook-login, digest-authentication

**[RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617)** specifies the *HTTP Basic and Digest Auth* standard and works as summarised in [Wikipedia's "Example with explanation" subsection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication#Example_with_explanation):

> - The client asks for a page that requires authentication but does not provide a username and password. Typically this is because the user simply entered the address or followed a link to the page.
> - The server responds with the 401 "client-error" response code, providing the authentication realm and a randomly-generated, single-use value called a nonce.
> - At this point, the browser will present the authentication realm (typically a description of the computer or system being accessed) to the user and prompt for a username and password. The user may decide to cancel at this point.
> - Once a username and password have been supplied, the client re-sends the same request but adds an authentication header that includes the response code.
> - In this example, the server accepts the authentication and the page is returned. If the username is invalid and/or the password is incorrect, the server might return the "401" response code and the client would prompt the user again.
>
> Note: A client may already have the required username and password without needing to prompt the user, e.g. if they have previously been stored by a web browser.

I am performing login using [OAuth2 draft-standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-29) as implemented by [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/).

**Given a server with an exposed public API (e.g.: JSONRPC or REST), how could the client-side JavaScript frontend be written to include the sort of functionality as the previously mentioned RFC 2617 example, but for Facebook auth?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an official (but unmaintained and now officially abandoned) repository of example client-side JavaScript library implementation examples, [click here for most recent fork](https://github.com/GunioRobot/connect-js). Here is the JQuery example from that page:

```
<head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>Connect JavaScript - jQuery Login Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Connect JavaScript - jQuery Login Example</h1>
      <div>
          <button id="login">Login</button>
          <button id="logout">Logout</button>
          <button id="disconnect">Disconnect</button>
      </div>
      <div id="user-info" style="display: none;"></div>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  <script>
      // initialize the library with the API key
      FB.init({
          apiKey: '48f06bc570aaf9ed454699ec4fe416df'
      });


      // fetch the status on load
      FB.getLoginStatus(handleSessionResponse);

      $('#login').bind('click', function () {
          FB.login(handleSessionResponse);
      });


      $('#logout').bind('click', function () {
          FB.logout(handleSessionResponse);
      });

      $('#disconnect').bind('click', function () {
          FB.api({
              method: 'Auth.revokeAuthorization'
          }, function (response) {
              clearDisplay();
          });
      });

      // no user, clear display
      function clearDisplay() {
          $('#user-info').hide('fast');
      }

      // handle a session response from any of the auth related calls
      function handleSessionResponse(response) {
          // if we dont have a session, just hide the user info
          if (!response.session) {
              clearDisplay();
              return;
          }

          // if we have a session, query for the user's profile picture and name
          FB.api({
              method: 'fql.query',
              query: 'SELECT name, pic FROM profile WHERE id=' + FB.getSession().uid
          },

          function (response) {
              var user = response[0];
              $('#user-info').html('<img src="' + user.pic + '">' + user.name).show('fast');
          });
      }
  </script>
```

Feel free to suggest improvements. Optimally I would like to see:

- Vanilla JavaScript implementation
- JSONRPC calls to facilitate login on personal server-end
- Routing (i.e.: redirect to signed-in user homepage on successful login)